# Statistics on renaming via JavaScript minifier

Tags: javascript, minify, google-closure-compiler, uglifyjs

I am new to the minification of JavaScript. This is the setting of the problem:

Assuming we have an original JavaScript code A and its minified code A′ (which is generated by a minifier like UglifyJS or Closure Compiler), how can I:

1. Count the number of variables which have been renamed, and
2. Map every variable's original name to its minified name

Any detailed instructions are welcomed, with the tool UglifyJS or Closure Compiler would be better :)

Comment: You probably want a minifier that will generate a [sourceMap](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/).

Comment: Can you clarify what your actual goal is?

Comment: @jfriend00 I did generate the sourceMap file. But it is hard to understand the mappings in there. Can your give some details? Thx!

Comment: @JethroLarson My goal is to calculate how many variables are affected in the minification, since some variables may not be renamed.

Comment: Since the point of a sourceMap is to map minimized code back to the original source, including variable names, it seems likely that all the info you want is in there.  I don't personally know the file format.  You will have to do some research to see what's been written about it.  Here's [some documatation](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1U1RGAehQwRypUTovF1KRlpiOFze0b-_2gc6fAH0KY0k/edit#) Google wrote about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two approaches:

1) The Closure Compiler can produce a "renaming map" for both properties and variables.  The map does not include unrenamed variables so that there would still be some work for you to do.  See the --variable_renaming_report command-line option https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/blob/master/src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/CommandLineRunner.java#L215.

2) The Closure Compiler and other tools produce source maps.  The source map can be used to map every byte back to the original character in the original.

For the second the Closure Compiler project includes a Java Library for reading source maps:
https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/blob/master/src/com/google/debugging/sourcemap/SourceMapConsumerV3.java#L225

There also exist javascript source map utilities:
https://github.com/mozilla/source-map/

Comment: Thanks! Using source-map library is convenient to map minified codes back to original source :)